# Array stays array when looped through `for`

Tags: raku

I'm looping through the `depends` array from a `META6.json`. I've loaded into a `Hash` using `JSON::Fast`. When I'm looping through it using a `for` loop, however, it only goes through the loop once, and the item is the same array:

```
use JSON::Fast;
my %meta = from-json(slurp("META6.json"));

for %meta<depends> -> $dependency {
    dd $dependency;
}
```

This piece of code returns

```
Array $dependency = $["Config::Parser::toml:ver<1.0.1+>", "Config:api<1>:ver<1.3.5+>", "Dist::Helper:ver<0.21.0+>", "Hash::Merge", "Terminal::Getpass:ver<0.0.5+>", "zef"]
```

I'm expecting it to loop through the `%meta<depends>` 6 times, which each iteration holding a different element from that array.

For good measure, this is the output of `dd %meta<depends>` from the example:

```
Array %meta = $["Config::Parser::toml:ver<1.0.1+>", "Config:api<1>:ver<1.3.5+>", "Dist::Helper:ver<0.21.0+>", "Hash::Merge", "Terminal::Getpass:ver<0.0.5+>", "zef"]
```

Why is the loop not looping the way I expected?

*EDIT*: I'm using the latest Rakudo Star:

```
This is Rakudo Star version 2018.04.1 built on MoarVM version 2018.04.1
implementing Perl 6.c.
```

Comment: `from-json` returns a single item, the `$[]` indicates it's an item or scalar. You'll have to de-itemize (reify) it via the decont operator `<>`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Even though `%meta<depends>` contains an `Array`, it is contained inside an item (container).  The `for` statement looks at that and decides there's only 1 thing to iterate over (the container).

This is easily remedied: by suffixing `.list` you convert the item to something `Iterable`, and thus it will iterate over the `Array` in the container:

```
for %meta<depends>.list -> $dependency {
```

A slightly shorter syntax for this is `@()`:

```
for @(%meta<depends>) -> $dependency {
```

EDIT: or use the syntax suggested by jjmerelo, which decontainerizes the element, and thus exposes the underlying `Array` to `for`:

```
for %meta<depends><> -> $dependency {
```

Answer (score 7):

This is a pitfall. Essentially this is like:

```
my $var = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
for $var -> $v {
    dd $v;
}
```

Which gives you: `$["a", "b", "c"]`

If you iterate an array with @ sigil it already acts as an Array, but when you have a list inside a scalar it will return the Array and not iterate inside it.

The solution is to use `.list` to make it act as a list instead of as a scalar.